# Need help trying to add cells and rows to a table using the days in month for loop

Tags: javascript

Trying to create a calendar that takes the days and adds them to the tr in the table. I have created all of my var, but I am having a hard time with the loop and and the start and end of calendar. Please help I am new to this.

```
"use strict";
var $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); };
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var monthName = ["January", "February", "March", "April","May","June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var month = d.getMonth();
var date = monthName[month] + "" + 1 + "" + year;
var tmp = new Date(date).toDateString();
var firstDay = tmp.substring(0, 3);
var dayName = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
var dayNumber = dayName.indexOf(firstDay);
var days = new Date(year, month+1, 0).getDate();

var getMonthText = function() {

    var monthText = monthName[d.getMonth()];
    var message = monthText + " " + year;
    document.getElementById("month_year").innerHTML = message;

};


var displayCalendar = function(dayNumber, days) {
    var table = document.getElementById("calendar");
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        row = table.insertRow(-1);
        for (var j = 0; j < days; j++) {
            var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
            cell.innerHTML = days[i];
        }
    }


    table.innerHTML = "";
    table.appendChild(row);


};

window.onload = function () {
 getMonthText();

 displayCalendar(dayNumber, days);
};


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calendar</title>

</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <h1 id="month_year">&nbsp;</h1>



        <table id="calendar">

            <tr><th>Sun</th><th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th><th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th></tr>
        </table>
    </main>
</body>
</html>

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 360px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 0 2em 1em;
}
h1 {
    color: blue;
    margin-bottom: .25em;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0.5 0 0 0.5;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some changes on your code. You were trying to access the position of an integer variable, thus resulting in undefined values. Also, i've implemented the logic of weekdays, inserting empty cells on the first week.

When the number of days in the week is past 6, it resets, appends the row to the table, then creates a new row.

```js
"use strict";
var $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); };
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var monthName = ["January", "February", "March", "April","May","June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var month = d.getMonth();
var date = monthName[month] + "" + 1 + "" + year;
var tmp = new Date(date).toDateString();
var firstDay = tmp.substring(0, 3);
var dayName = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
var dayNumber = dayName.indexOf(firstDay);
var days = new Date(year, month+1, 0).getDate();

var getMonthText = function() {

    var monthText = monthName[d.getMonth()];
    var message = monthText + " " + year;
    document.getElementById("month_year").innerHTML = message;

};


var displayCalendar = function(dayNumber, days) {
  var table = document.getElementById("calendar");
  var row = document.createElement("tr");

  var weekdays = 0;
  var firstDate = new Date(year, month, 1);
  var weekdays = firstDate.getDay();
  var current_row = table.insertRow(-1);
  for(var i=0; i < weekdays; i++) {
    current_row.insertCell(-1);
  }
  table.appendChild(current_row);
  weekdays--;
  for(var ds = 1; ds <= days; ds++) {
    if(weekdays == 6){
      weekdays = 0;
      table.appendChild(current_row);
      current_row = table.insertRow(-1);
    } else {
      weekdays++;
    }
    var cell = current_row.insertCell(-1);
    cell.innerHTML = ds;
  }
};

 getMonthText();

 displayCalendar(dayNumber, days);
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 360px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 0 2em 1em;
}
h1 {
    color: blue;
    margin-bottom: .25em;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0.5 0 0 0.5;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
    <main>
        <h1 id="month_year">&nbsp;</h1>



        <table id="calendar">

            <tr><th>Sun</th><th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th><th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th></tr>
        </table>
    </main>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. What does "ds" stand for or do?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer "ds" is the variable containing the current day. In your code, you used J as the day variable.